# Difference between format specifiers %s and %c for "*p" and "p" in string

Tags: c, pointers

why this program behaving like this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
char *p = "Pointers";
printf("%s", p);
}
```

Output : Pointers

Here i tried to print the string value using "*p" but it crashing while compiling. if i print the value using "p" mean it printing the string instead of address of memory location of "p"

Please help on this

Comment: may i know why downvote for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

`printf` expects a pointer for the `%s` format specifier. If you pass in `*p`, you are de-referenceing `p` and actually passing in the first byte of your string (e.g. 'P'). `printf` is then treating the that first 'P' of your string as a pointer, and it's leading it to an invalid memory location.

As a general rule, in C you don't usually pass strings by value. Instead you pass pointers to strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the print the value of the *address* of the `p` variable [vs. what it points to], use:

```
printf("%p\n",&p);
```

This will give you the address of `p` on the stack, which should be a fairly high memory address (e.g. `0x7ffdb4066268`).

If you want the address of the string constant pointed to by `p` [vs. the string], do:

```
printf("%p\n",p);
```

You'll get something like `0x400xxx`